# MySQL - How to get all Customers who haven't been called in the last two hours

Tags: mysql, sql, join, foreign-keys, foreign-key-relationship

In my MySQL-db I have two tables `customer` and `call`.

*Customer* has two fields: *id* and *name*.

*Call* has the fields:

```
id 
customer (NOT NULL FK)
dateOfCall (NOT NULL DATE)
timeOfCall (NOT NULL TIME).
```

There are Customers which haven't been called yet. A Customer can be called multiple times.

How do I make a query to get all customers who haven't been called in the last two hours?

SQL Fiddle with the schema and some minimal data: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/5c80f/1 (Bear in mind that the SQL Fiddle Server might be in another timezone than you!)

Comment: could you please prepare a schema in http://sqlfiddle.com/

Comment: @motto: Good idea. I now included an SQL Fiddle at the of the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We need to check against the last time a person received a call. Here is the updated sql.

```
Select 
    cust.* 
from 
    `customer` cust 
left join 
(
    select
    customer
    from `call` cl 
    group by customer
    having 
    max(STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(cl.dateOfCall, ' ', cl.timeOfCall), '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s')) >= date_sub(NOW(), interval 2 hour)
) aa on cust.id = aa.customer
where aa.customer is null
```

Comment: Yes, I also want customers who have never been called. I want all customers who haven't been called for the last two hours.

Comment: modified the query.

Comment: It was stupid of me to name the table call. could you please escape it in your query (\`call\`) so it won't be taken for a keyword?

Comment: escaped the names.

Comment: @Mathias- check the sql now. We need to check against the last time a person received a call not against all the calls he received as we did before.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * FROM customer 
WHERE id NOT IN (
    SELECT DISTINCT customer FROM `call` 
    WHERE timeOfCall NOT BETWEEN 
    SUBTIME(curtime() , '02:00:00') AND curtime());
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [date_sub](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function%5Fdate-sub) with left outer join:

```
SELECT * 
FROM `customer` as cu
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
(
SELECT * FROM `call` WHERE 
 call.dateOfCall >= DATE_FORMAT(DATE_SUB(CURTIME(), INTERVAL 2 HOUR),'%Y-%m-%d') 
 AND
 ( call.timeOfCall > DATE_SUB(CURTIME(), INTERVAL 2 HOUR ) )
) as ca
  ON (ca.customer = cu.id)
  WHERE ca.customer IS NULL;
```

[fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/bdf006/76)

Edit: Replaced date_add with date_sub. No need for confusion.

Comment: There seems to be something wrong. When I run the query, it returns only Mesut as an answer, it misses out on Mehtap and Maksym. (Tried at 22:21 26.7.16)

Comment: This looks promising and the result set is correct. What I don't understand in your Query: `WHERE call.customer IS NULL` -> call.customer is a NOT NULL field. `call.dateOfCall <  DATE_SUB(NOW(),INTERVAL 2 HOUR)` -> What is this doing? @Motto:

Comment: I changed the sample data so that cu #9 got called within the last 2 hours, so he shouldn't appear in the result set but he does: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/bdf006/1

Yes, but why are checking call.customer to be NULL? That field will never be NULL. @Motto

Comment: @Mathias It seems like I have made a mistake before and fixed it now. About null, in the result set it can be null and it is null. Because you are seeing a modified result set with the joined tables. If there is a record in the joined table it won't be null but if there isn't it is reflected null in the result set and this is how we filter the result set.